# Top-down approach in C: Interface implemented via multiple C files

Tags: c, interface, embedded

I am responsible for designing the software architecture of an embedded system in C90 (which is dictated by the target hardware compiler). It shall be easily built against a couple of targets (traditional testing, Software-In-The-Loop, final hardware). Therefore I took a top-down approach or, designing for an interface:

Once defined the data flows of the system (inputs, outputs, ...) I have created generical interfaces in the form of .H files that need to be implemented by the targets.

Therefore, and for the sake of the question, let them be two:

```
imeasures.h --> Measures needed by the algorithm
icomm.h --> Data flow to and from the algorithm to other devices
```

For the production target, suppose that **all the measures but one** (e.g. Engine Speed) are taken using **ADCmeasures** module, and the last mentioned one (Engine Speed) is provided by **RS232comm** module.

**Question 1**

Is it OK if **imeasures.h** is implemented using both **ADCmeasures** and **RS232comm** modules in the following form?

```
imeasures.h <--is implemented BY-- imeasuresImpl.c
imeasuresImpl.c --> calls functions from ADCmeasures.h and RS232comm.h
```

Therefore, switching targets would imply changing imeasuresImpl and the rest of callees.

**Question 2**

Due to the overhead the previous method may suppose (which could be mitigated using inline functions, indeed) , I also thought about a ¿less elegant? form:

```
imeasures.h <-- is partially implemented by ADCmeasures.c
imeasures.h <-- is partially implemented by RS232comm.c
```

Which pitfalls do you see? I can see that, for example, if imeasures.h consists of a single getter method which returns a struct, I would have to partially fill the struct in both of the partial implementations. Or, in turn, provide different getter methods, and then I would be deciding beforehand a layout of the implementation which would break the top-down principle.

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: Q1: What is the problem with 'switching targets' and why does it 'change imeasuresimpl'?
Q2: What overhead? Are there very extreme performance requirements?

Comment: @meaning-matters: Q1: For testing purposes I may use a mock implementation of imeasures. Instead in Software-In-The-Loop I will communicate with the Simulation package. Q2: I know beforehand that the hardware will cope with the requirements by a not so big margin.

Comment: I generally don't like non-symmetric header/source files. If there is `measures.c`, there is always `measures.h`. Mixing declarations to one header from multiple modules is messy. Especially if you need to add or remove modules later.

Comment: @user694733 I suppose that comment is on the Q2 form? I think it's quite messy too. When it comes to Q1, distinguishing imeasures.h from imeasuresImpl.c is a matter of convention inherited from the OO interface-implementation paradigm, just to clarify.

Comment: @Manex Yeah, I figured it was a convention. But I don't think it's that useful in C; by default `x.h` is the interface, and `x.c` is the implementation. Anyway, I think it makes sense in this situation to have single `ADCmeasures.h`, and organize respective source files in folders, like `src/hw/ADCmeasures.c` and `src/emulation/ADCmeasures.c`, and compile only one you need.

Comment: @user694733 It makes sense the by-default meaning of C and H files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First, some assumptions on the situation, the requirements**

So I assume that through `imeasures.h`, preferably you would like to get an interface with a single `get` function which would return you a structure nicely populated with the most fresh measurements. While it is possible, you may accept some other functions like `run` which would run the processes necessary for the measurements, and an `init` to initialize the stuff (I mean with "possible" that there are ways I sometimes explored by which you can get around without these two latter functions).

As you tell, I assume you would like to separate an as thin hardware interface as possible, so you could easier apply simulation for testing, or later you would have less to reimplement when porting to different hardware.

As the interface suggest, you would like to hide the split (that one of your measurements come from RS232).

**Solving with something like Q1, the architecture**

Your take with Q1 seems to be an okay approach for laying down the architecture to meet these requirements. For Q2 I think "forget that", I can't conceive any reasonable solution which would appear like that.

My approach, just like your Q1, would require at least three implementation file.

- On the top would be an `imeasures.c` (I would stick to this name, since that's the usual way of doing these, and there is no very good reason to do anything different here). This file would implement the whole `imeasures.h` interface, in it containing the logic for assembling the measurements, and dispatching the hardware-specific components. It would not contain anything hardware-specific by itself.
- An `RS232comm.c` (and `.h`) would realize the RS232 hardware interface. I would do this as generic as reasonable, within the necessities of meeting the requirements (for example if it would only need to receive, I would only implement a receiver adequate for the project here). The goal is to have something which meets the project's requirements, however if needed, may be re-used for other projects on the same (or similar) hardware.
- An `ADCcomm.c` (and `.h`). Note that I did not name it `ADCmeasures.c` for a good reason: since I don't want to have anything specific for the actual measurements here. Just like above: something necessary by the requirements, but generic enough so it might be possible to be reused.

Following this, it is likely that you get an `imeasures.c` which does not need to be altered in any means for the simulation (has no hardware specific code), so can also be tested in that testing environment. You also get useful little hardware specific components which you can reuse for new projects (in my case it happened quite frequently as many times electrical engineers would iterate on the same piece of hardware for later projects).

Usually you shouldn't have to be concerned about overhead. Design first, optimize only where it is actually necessary. If you design well, you may even likely to end up with an end product performing better, just because you don't have to battle with messy performance code (or "I thought it would perform better" code), taking your time from recognizing the real bottlenecks, and time from either discovering better algorithms or optimizing those parts which actually need it.

Well, hope it helps in getting across this!

Comment: Your design proposal is almost as I have been considering these days, while writing Q1 I felt like I was coming up with the proper answer. Thank you for the final advices.